# How should I translate "isomorphisme près" to English?

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-french

While reading a French mathematical text, I encountered the phrase "unique à un isomorphisme près". How should I translate "isomorphisme près" to English? Does it mean "canonical isomorphism"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

French speaker here. "Unique à un isomorphisme près" means "unique up to an isomorphism".

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure! You're welcome!

Comment: More generally, [À quelque chose près](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80_quelque_chose_pr%C3%A8s) on the French Wikipedia.